# How to call function from another class anywhere

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this method for check if token expired. I want to insert this in a class of function and having the ability to call this works anywhere on my application.

```
   Future<http.Response> _checkToken() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var url = kUrlAPI + 'checkToken/';

    var response = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + prefs.getString('token'),
        });

    var convertDataToJson = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if(convertDataToJson['code'] == 401){
      showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => CustomDialog(
          pressedAction: () {
            //Token expired. Logout and redirect to login page
          },
          type: 'w',
          title: kWarningTitle,
          description: kGenericError,
          buttonText: kCloseText,
        ),
      );
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the method static, and call the method with the class name, Like this:

```
YourClass._checkToken();
```

Comment: `LoginScreen._checkToken();`

`The method '_checkToken' isn't defined for the type 'LoginScreen'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '_checkToken'.`

Comment: change your method to static, like this: static Future<http.Response> _checkToken()

Comment: the same error. I use `Function._checkToken()` inside the onPressed(){}

Comment: did you put the method inside a class called Function?

Comment: try to use another name in your class, do not use Function

Answer (score 0):

You should make you method `public` first and use it like @Jean Lucas.

- Other way is with mixin:

```dart
mixin YourMixin {
  checkToken() {
    ...
  }
}

class YourClass extends StatelessWidget with YourMixin {
  const YourClass({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        checkToken();
      },
      child: Text(""),
    );
  }
}
```